# Background-image:URL jumbles the url. when made in JS

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

In my Js script i tried escaping,setting string to another complete variable and everything i can think of doing.
But cant figure out why the "/ "character in the background-image:url("../") is giving me such a hard time.

Here is a piece of code from my Js script.

```
 let image = "../../" + value.image;
receptenMarkup += '<div class="receptImage" style="background-image:url("../../'+ value.image +'");" alt="test"></div><img src="'+ image + '">';
```

"../../'+ value.image +'" comes back correctly in the console.log as the path.
Image comes back as the correct path.
Example:

```
../../images/recepten/thai-chicken.jpg
```

My console.log of the entire markup also shows a correct path.

```
<div class="receptImage" style="background-image:url("../../images/recepten/noodle- soup.jpg");" alt="test">
```

but!! here is the Result in the inspector..
RESULT INSPECTOR:

```
<div class="receptImage" style="background-image:url(" ..="" images="" recepten="" noodle-soup.jpg");"="" alt="test"></div><img src="../../images/recepten/noodle-soup.jpg">
```

Notice the image url works great and fine!
The CSS part on the other hand gets all sorts of crazy.

I cant get this to work properly and point the background image to the right path.
I collect a lot of Json data and make cards based on that.
the background image needs to be in a div so i can style it in RWD and not deform like an image tag does.

Somehow i cant get this to work.

Can anyone please give me pointers?

I tried
1: using ../../ to escape ../../ to escape
2: using just "/'value.image'" to go to the root of the website as W3 suggests, no go.

I bee at this for hours now and my deadline is approaching..
Please can anyone explain why the / becomes a space and i get stuff like image=.. in there which i didnt even type that wat.
URL and IMG react differently.

[image: code and inspector]
[image: json i get the data from]

Comment: you need to escape your double quotes inside the `url("` otherwise the you are closing off your style tag

Answer (score 0):

The problem isn't the `/`, it's the mismatched quote characters delimiting the strings and attribute values.

The simple fix for this is to use a template literal:

```js
receptenMarkup += `<div class="receptImage" style="background-image: url('../../${value.image}');" alt="test"></div><img src="${image}">`;
```

Side note; I would suggest making all paths relative to the site root, not relative to the current page.

Comment: you are a god sent!
Thank you!. 
${} didnt even come to mind.